# Not sure why this code isnt working. The program should search through this word list and remove any words that include the letter A

Tags: javascript, list, function, loops

This is being done on code.org, for some reason it removes some words with the letter A but not all, im not sure why it wont work.

```
    var wordList = ["abase", "abate", "abbey", "abbot", "abhor", "abide", "abled", "abode", 
"abort", "about", "above", "abuse", "abyss", "acorn", "acrid", "actor", "acute", "adage", 
"adapt",  "adept", "admin", "admit", "adobe", "adopt", "adore", "adorn", "adult", "affix", 
"afire", "afoot", "afoul", "after", "bulge", "bulky", "bully", "bunch", "bunny", "burly", 
"burnt", "burst", "bused", "bushy", "butch", "butte", "buxom", "buyer", "bylaw", "cabal", 
"cabby", "cabin", "cable", "cacao", "cache", "cacti", "pique", "setup", "seven", "sever", 
"wrote", "wrung", "wryly", "yacht", "yearn", 
"yeast", "yield", "young", "youth", "zebra", "zesty", "zonal"];
var wrongLettersList = ["a"];
var unsureLettersList = [];
var goodLettersList = [];
onEvent("wrongLetterInput", "input", function( ) {
  appendItem(wrongLettersList, getText("wrongLetterInput"));
  setProperty("wrongLetterInput","text", "");
  setProperty("wrongLetterInput", "placeholder", "Letters inputted: "+wrongLettersList);
  listFilter(wrongLettersList, unsureLettersList, goodLettersList);
});

function listFilter(wrongLetters, unsureLetters, goodLetters) {
  for(var j = 0; j<wordList.length; j++) {
    if(wordList[j].includes(wrongLetters[0])){
      wordList.splice(j, 1);
    }
  }
  console.log(wordList);
}
```

Comment: You have a stack of books. You pull out the bottom book. The other books move down a position. You move to book "2" which is actually "3" when you started.

Comment: Just use filter()

Comment: Or start at the end of the list and work your way toward the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you skip one word once you splice.
The easy, but not the best choice is:

```
function listFilter(wrongLetters, unsureLetters, goodLetters) {
  for(var j = 0; j<wordList.length; j++) {
    if(wordList[j].includes(wrongLetters[0])){
      wordList.splice(j, 1);
      j-=1; // ---> decrement 1 from j so you don't skip a word
    }
  }
  console.log(wordList);
}
```

But definitely, as above said, using filter is much easier and readable.

```
return wordList.filter(w => !w.includes(wrongLettersList[0]));
```